# Calculation appropriate angular step depth in depthmapX

Tags: syntax, angles, depth

I am a new depthmapX user in which trying to calculate segment step depth from specific segment to store cumulative angles for each segment. Is there anyone who can provide advice to implement it?

depthmapX
http://www.spacesyntax.net/software/

*Network conditions are shown below:*

- Network is composed of center lines produced from polygon of alleyway in a city bock
- Alleyway has 5 entrances from sidewalk at the fringe of the block and all alleyways are connected
- Center lines are produced from Voronoi polygons, so, there are three characteristics in the network: 1) each segment has very short distance (spreading from less than 1 meter to  3 meters) to replicate  shapes of the alleyway, 2) there are a number of segments between actual intersections due to previous characteristics, and 3) due to the nature of Voronoi polygons, each segment is angled slightly though it is actually straight alleyway.

*Followings are the manipulations that I did:*

- Convert dxf file to axial map and fix disconnection of some lines which can be found by angular step depth analysis specifying a link
- Convert axial map into segment map and conduct angular step depth analysis
  *I confirmed both analyses shows the same result (axial map also can conduct angular step depth analysis)

*The results show following issues:*

- As there are a number of segments between actual intersections with small angle, cumulative angles from selected segment increase gradually
- Due to above result, segment angle after turning right or left does not show significant difference before the turning
- Expected results are that segments between intersection have the same or similar value and certain amount of cumulative angels differ from the ones before turning

To solve the issues above, following countermeasures have taken:
- Simplified network, for instance, one segment between two intersections has built to confirm calculation result
- However, at T-shape intersection crossing at right angle for instance, cumulative angles of segments after taking turn does not show 1 point increase compared with the one before the turning
- I thought Tulip analysis can be applied to neglect such small angles as it can approximate angles, however it does not work for the analysis for selected segment

The first issues may be caused by the network specifications and the latter may be more general issue.
I wish if someone has solved similar issue before or provide solution or hints to solve it.